# "Trying to access array offset on value of type bool"

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7, php5, checkbox

Actualmente estoy tratando de solventar un problema con checkboxes que me tiene loco. El código utilizado es sencilo: Se busca detectar cuando un usuario ya tiene el checkbox tildado y si se lo tilda o destilda se lo guarda en la base de datos.
El problema subyace que me sale este aviso: "Trying to access array offset on value of type bool"
El código en cuestión es el siguiente:

```
if($row3['insignia_id'] == $row2['insignia_id'])
            {
                $checked = 'checked=checked';
            } else 
            {
                $checked = null;
            }
```

Y la línea involucrada es la siguiente:

```
if($row3['insignia_id'] == $row2['insignia_id'])
```

A cotinuación les dejo todo el código:

```
            <?php

        $stmt2 = $db->query('SELECT insignia_id, nombre_i FROM insignias ORDER BY insignia_id');
        while($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()){

            $stmt3 = $db->prepare('SELECT insignia_id FROM insignias_users_id WHERE insignia_id = :insignia_id AND id = :id') ;
            $stmt3->execute(array(':insignia_id' => $row2['insignia_id'], ':id' => $row['id']));
            $row3 = $stmt3->fetch(); 

            if($row3['insignia_id'] == $row2['insignia_id'])
            {
                $checked = 'checked=checked';
            } else 
            {
                $checked = null;
            }

            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='insignia_id[]' value='".$row2['insignia_id']."' $checked> ".$row2['nombre_i']."<br />";
        }
```

### ?>

EDIT: Hice la siguiente modificación para ver si lo podía solucionar pero me salta el $checked como indefinido.

```
        if (isset($row3['insignia_id']) && isset($row['insignia_id'])) {
        if($row3['insignia_id'] == $row2['insignia_id'])
        {
            $checked = 'checked=checked';
        } else 
        {
            $checked = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Quizá deberías repensar tu código, por ejemplo, podrías lanzar una sola consulta uniendo las tablas con `JOIN`. Dicho eso, el error actual hace pensar que `$row2` o `$row3` o ambas son booleanos, debido a que la consulta ha fallado. Depura tus variables usando `var_dump` y te ahorrarás horas y muchos dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Me podrías ayudar a hacer algo como eso? o al menos un ejemplo, porque ando re perdido con esto...

Comment: Claro que sí, pero para ayudarte lo primero es entender el problema. Tu pregunta no permite entender del todo lo que quieres hacer. Sugiero que la edites para explicar con más claridad el contexto y lo que quieres lograr en sí. Indica también el resultado de las depuraciones hechas usando `var_dump`, no ignores esa sugerencia: si vas a programar es fundamental aprender a **depurar**, te ahorrarás horas y muchos dolores de cabeza. Si no entiendes lo que digo interesate por el tema, investigando el uso de `var_dump` y aprendiendo a leer los logs de errores.